# How to create a function calculating correlation/correlation matrix using J?

Tags: j

I have already wrote the following code by my own, which calculates the correlation/correlation matrix step by step:

```
a=: 1 2 3
b=: 2 3 4
getmean=: +/%#
getmdevn=: -getmean
getvariance1=: (getmean@:*:)@getmdevn

getvariance1 a
getvariance1 b
corr_a_b=: getmean (a*b) - getmean a * getmean b
```

What is the best way to calculate correlation/corellation matrix in J by using a single function? Or is there any way to combine all my code into one function?

P.S. I just found some libraries like 'numeric' in J. However, it seems that there is no documentation of those libraries online. Does anyone know where to find details of those libraries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For practical purposes, [@EelVex is right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44807270/2562182), you should use the libraries shipped with J, as they encapsulate "best practice" as JSoftware perceives it.

However, for  pedagogical, intellectual, and aesthetic reasons, I am a big fan of [Oleg Kobchenko's triumph](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-June/007206.html):

```
 corr =: (+/@:* % *&(+/)&.:*:)&(- +/%#)
```

As [I mentioned in 2013](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2013-February/031642.html), it's got specimens of all the major compositions in J:

- fork `f g h`
- hook `f g`
- atop `f@:g`
- compose `f&g`
- under `f&.:g`

And with the exception of `&`, precisely one of each. For a very real, very common calculation. Neat!

And, if you can read J, it's a clear improvement over the standard mathematical notation, because you can *literally see some of the symmetries* that underlie that formula: the left tine is the sum of the product (`+/@:*`) and right is the product of the sums (`*&(+/)`).

The whole middle fork is an elegant butterfly with beautiful symmetric wings (complete with antennae on the head `%`!).

```
   c=:+/@:* % *&(+/)

   5!:4<'c'
         +- / --- +
  +- @: -+- *      
  +- %             
--+      +- *      
  +- & --+- / --- +
```

Plus the whole thing is algebraically reduced. What that means is, in contrast to the standard mathematical notation where you have *x*s and *y*s and *x̄*s and *ȳ*s scattered all over the place, in `corr` it's clear that the very first thing we do is standardize the variables, and thereafter all we ever deal with is the delta, and so we are immune to changes in scale, units of measurement, etc.

As a further example of J notation shedding light on the underlying mathematical structures, [Oleg took the reduction a step further](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-June/007209.html), and cut this [jem](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-May/006503.html):

```
Cr=: +/@:*&(% +/&.:*:)&(- +/ % #)
```

As I discussed [later in the 2013 thread](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2013-February/031662.html), I still prefer the original because of its structural
symmetries, but this version also has its merits: it *makes it clear that correlation is simply the linear combination of the series, after some
normalization/standardization*.

```
sum             =:  +/         
of              =:  @          
the_product     =:  *          
after           =:  &          
scaling         =:  % +/&.:*:
after           =:  &          
standardizing   =:  - +/%#


corr =: sum of the_product after scaling after standardizing
```

We're getting insight into the *math* simply by trying different ways of expressing ourselves!

But again, for practical purposes, I suggest you follow the advice in @EelVex's answer. As [Henry Rich observed](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-June/007180.html) in the thread where Oleg discovered these beautiful forms:

> I **don't think either of these forms is useful for real work**, since they involve subtracting big near-equal numbers, but **I learned something about the computation by writing them**.

Which [Oleg then demonstrated](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-June/007208.html) concretely:

> That is easily seen running [the Wikipedia stability test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Computing_correlation_accurately_in_a_single_pass):
>
> ```
>    CR=: (+/@:* % *&(+/)&.:*:)&(- +/ % #)
>
>   0j20":CR/900000000(+,:-)1+i.1000000
> _1.00000000000000000000
>
>   COR f.
> (+/ % #)@:*&(- (+/ % #)) % *&(%:@(+/ % #)@:*:@:- (+/ % #))
>
>   0j20":COR/900000000(+,:-)1+i.1000000
> _1.00000000000000000000
>
>   0j20":c/900000000(+,:-)1+i.1000000
> 1.00000229430253350000
>
>   load'stats'
>   0j20":corr/900000000(+,:-)1+i.1000000
> _0.99999999999619615000
> ```

But, then, that's not the point. Ultimately, I think [June Kim summed it up best](http://www.jsoftware.com/pipermail/programming/2007-June/007181.html) in 2007:

> While I try to translate a mathematical expression into a J expression, I often discover hidden patterns in the expression with great joy.
>
> It sometimes leads me to a path to new insights.

Comment: This was a neat peak into the history of J. I stumbled upon the same phrase in [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9115/6710) a year ago.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is fine and in fact very similar to what is defined in 'stats' library.

```
load'stats'
varp a               NB. variance of population a
  0.666667
a covp b             NB. covariance of a/b
  0.666667
```

Take a look at the [stats library](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Addons/stats/base)

I would write your `corr_a_b` as dyadic function:

```
 corr_a_b =: ((getmean @: *) - (* &: getmean))
```

Comment: Thanks Eelvex! I didn't even notice that there is a library called 'stats'. Could you kindly inform me of where I can find those libraries?

Comment: Just found it. Thanks!